# Is it possible to display a bar on top of BottomSheet in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet, bottombar

I am using a `BottomSheet` in my application, which contain some list items, and I am also using a Tab bar view in my whole application (at bottom of screen).

Is it possible and how can I display my that Tab Bar still in bottom of screen, and `BottomSheet` should also appear (on defined offset), but below my Tab Bar.

How can I adjust and arrange these layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show Below link. Also you can add multiple tab bar in bottom layout.

https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html

Comment: Just read above link but it says: **Don’t use a bottom navigation bar for fewer than three destinations (use tabs instead).**  Does Tab work same way?

Comment: I have not tried this but I believe this solution will work as well. For my case, I am able to use my original custom tab bar at bottom of my original/main view, and by setting tab bar `gravity` at bottom and setting its `elevation` higher.